# How to get a data set to acutally read as values in order to change them?

Tags: python

Example: `Data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`. I want to subtract the mean value from each value. I tried using

```
L= (Data)

G= L - 5.4  

print(G)
```

but python doesn't read Data as actual values. How do I get python to read the individual values in my data set and subtract the mean from each one?

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Data is tuple. You need to do sth for every item in that tuple! `G = tuple([num - 5.4 for i in Data])`

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if it solved your problem (click on the check next to the answer which then turns green).

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
new_data = tuple(i-sum(data)/float(len(data)) for i in data)
```

Output:

```
(-4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: Might be better to calculate the mean separately as it is now calculated in each iteration, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> {l - 5.4 for l in Data}
set([1.5999999999999996, -1.4000000000000004, 0.5999999999999996, 
3.5999999999999996, 2.5999999999999996, -2.4000000000000004, 
-3.4000000000000004, -4.4, -0.40000000000000036])
```

Comment: I clung onto the word "set" in the subject a little too much there. Didn't notice the code was actually a tuple. So I used set comprehension instead of the other tuple([...]) answers given.

Comment: yeah, i've noticed. i'm asking about those numbers, why is it e.g. `2.5999999999999996` and not `2.6`? i'm quite experienced with python, but this is really new for me...

Comment: Due to the floating point numbers, just round it as well to your desired s.f. ">>> {round(l - 5.4, 2) for l in Data}" gives set([1.6, -1.4, 3.6, 0.6, 2.6, -2.4, -3.4, -4.4, -0.4])

Comment: Problem with the set is that it is not ordered. It is not clear from the question whether the order matters though :)

Comment: Oh, I entirely agree. Like I said I hung onto the word "set" too much there ;-)

Comment: @Python_Begginer You need to accept the best answer that helped you. (This is why people help and answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It's an iterable. You can iterate over it with somthing like:

```
G = [number - 5.4 for number in Data]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark the answer that helped you to make the question answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `numpy` if you like:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(Data)

new_data = data - np.mean(data)
```

This will give the desired output

```
array([-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

If you cannot use numpy then  - as in the other answers - a list comprehension is probably the best choice. As a small variation of [Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655733/1534017), I would calculate the mean first (otherwise it is calculated in each iteration):

```
m = float(sum(Data)) / len(Data)
new_data = tuple([vi - m for vi in Data])
```

This yields

```
 (-4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: @Python_Begginer: Glad we could help. Don't forget to accept the most helpful answer by clicking on the small check next to the answer (it will turn green) Once you have sufficient reputation you can then also upvote helpful answers.